# External Oak Door refurbishment

Tags: doors, exterior, hardwood-refinishing

When we moved into our house 22 years ago we has a new oak front door made and fitted. I treated it with a few coats of Danish oil and haven't done anything to it since then.

It is beginning to look a bit dirty and I wonder what the best way of cleaning and refinishing it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a mild  brightening agent to clean it up,  go mild! nothing harsh. Then sand lightly until you get a fairly uniform appearance.  Then re-oil with Danish oil (great product choice you made years ago, btw).  You should probably clean it up , sand lightly every few years and re-oil.  The nice thing about oils is they aren't a solid surface finish and can be touched up as needed.  (BTW, I post here regularly as George Anderson, but I"m on the road and forgot my main SE password!)

Comment: You can [merge your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) once you get back from your trip.

Comment: I find password managers to be useful.  Only one password to remember(a very big suck if you forget it).  I don't even know most of my passwords.

Comment: If you're on the road, hopefully having fun, what are you doing here??? Sign out and have a beer!!

Comment: @JACK  Well sorta on the road, actually I'm at my cabin, fixing things, cleaning, painting, getting ready to list it for sale. My wife and 2 grand-kids are with me, so it's not bad.  I just enjoy this site and like to contribute.

Comment: @georgeanderson many thanks. I'm in the UK and am not totally familiar with the term brightening agent. Is that like a mild detergent? Would sugar soap be too harsh?

Comment: I don't know what sugar soap is, so I can't say.  If you have access to a reputable paint store, they might be able to recommend a product.  Product recommendations are OT here. As always, test a small spot to see if it has the desired effect.